# How does conditional expression compare strings?

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'Using conditional expression:'
[[ ' ' < '0' ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
[[ ' a' < '0a' ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
echo 'Using test:'
[ ' ' \< '0' ] && echo ok || echo not ok
[ ' a' \< '0a' ] && echo ok || echo not ok
```

The output is:

```
Using conditional expression:
ok
not ok
Using test:
ok
ok
```

`bash --version`: `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

`uname -a`: `Linux linuxmint 3.8.0-19-generic`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash manual says:

> When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.  The test command sorts using ASCII ordering.

This boils down to using strcoll(3) or strcmp(3) respectively.

Use the following program (strcoll_strcmp.c) to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s str1 str2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("strcoll('%s', '%s'): %d\n",
           argv[1], argv[2], strcoll(argv[1], argv[2]));
    printf("strcmp('%s', '%s'): %d\n",
           argv[1], argv[2], strcmp(argv[1], argv[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

Note the difference:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ./strcoll_strcmp ' a' '0a'
strcoll(' a', '0a'): -16
strcmp(' a', '0a'): -16

$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ./strcoll_strcmp ' a' '0a'
strcoll(' a', '0a'): 10
strcmp(' a', '0a'): -16
```

Exactly why these compare as such I'm not sure. This must be due to some English lexicographical sorting rules. I think the exact rules are described in [ISO 14651 Method for comparing character strings and description of the common template tailorable ordering](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html) and the accompanying template table. Glibc contains this data in the source tree under `libc/localedata/locales`.

Comment: But why a single space is less than 'a' in both cases?

Comment: @updogliu See an addition at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I tried several cases. It seems that the leading whitespaces are simply discarded in `strcoll`.

Comment: It can be as weird as this example...http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcoll

Comment: @updogliu Discarding whitespace would make sense. It's all to do with sorting dictionaries, phone books and such, which is highly dependent on language and customs.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour that you're observing can be explained by the following from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

```
bash-4.1 and later use the current locale’s collation sequence and strcoll(3).
```

You seem to be looking for comparison based on ASCII collation.  You can change the behavior by setting either `compat32` or `compat40`.

```
$ cat test
shopt -s compat40
echo 'Using conditional expression:'
[[ ' ' < '0' ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
[[ ' a' < '0a' ]] && echo ok || echo not ok
echo 'Using test:'
[ ' ' \< '0' ] && echo ok || echo not ok
[ ' a' \< '0a' ] && echo ok || echo not ok
$ bash test
Using conditional expression:
ok
ok
Using test:
ok
ok
```

From the manual:

```
compat32
If set, Bash changes its behavior to that of version 3.2 with respect to locale-specific string comparison when using the ‘[[’ conditional command’s ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators. Bash versions prior to bash-4.0 use ASCII collation and strcmp(3); bash-4.1 and later use the current locale’s collation sequence and strcoll(3). 
compat40
If set, Bash changes its behavior to that of version 4.0 with respect to locale-specific string comparison when using the ‘[[’ conditional command’s ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators (see previous item) and the effect of interrupting a command list.
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<` operator when used inside `[ ]` or `[[  ]]` compares the two strings according to  ASCII alphabetical order. That means that `a` is less than `b`. The caveat here, is that because `[ ]` is a bit difficult and arcane you need to escape `<`, other wise base thinks you want to do a redirect.

The two tests are however equvivalent:

```
[ 'a' \< 'b' ] && echo ok
[[ 'a' < 'b' ]] && echo ok
```

In your example `' a'` is definately less than `'0a'`, as a space has decimal value 20, and '0' has the value 48.

So I think you've found a bug there.

```
[ ' a' \< '0a' ]
```

and

```
[[ ' a' < '0a' ]]
```

should be equivalent, and the one in `[ ]` is correct.